# Show that $\partial_t g^{jl}=-g^{jp}(\partial_tg_{pq})g^{ql}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

If $g_{ij}$ are the components of a Riemannian metric and $\partial_tg_{ij}=-2R_{ij}$, how to show

$$\partial_t g^{jl}=-g^{jp}(\partial_tg_{pq})g^{ql}\,?$$

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  I guess $g^{jl}=g_{pi}g^{jp}g^{ql}$, but although it's right , according to product rule, there are 3 part after $\partial_t$.

Comment: It's seemly very easy ,but I don't know  where to start.

Comment: Note, $\partial_tg_{ij} = -2R_{ij}$ is not needed to prove the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\delta_p^l = g_{pq}g^{ql}.$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ we get

$$0 = (\partial_tg_{pq})g^{ql} + g_{pq}(\partial_tg^{ql})$$

so

$$g_{pq}(\partial_t g^{ql}) = - (\partial_t g_{pq})g^{ql}.$$

Applying $g^{jp}$ to both sides gives

$$g^{jp}g_{pq}(\partial_t g^{ql}) = - g^{jp}(\partial_t g_{pq})g^{ql}.$$

As $g^{jp}g_{pq} = \delta^j_q$, we have

$$\partial_tg^{jl} = - g^{jp}(\partial_t g_{pq})g^{ql}.$$